# Is there a way to assign object in a for loop python

Tags: python, class, object

I have a class called MediaFiles, and I am getting a path from the user from which I get the full path, name of the file and the file extension, what I am trying to do is store each of these

Comment: is the formatting correct on this? currently it makes no sense the way it is arranged. also you are treating your object as a list/dict which it is not

Comment: The error message includes the line that failed. If you post the entire message then we can see which line had the problem without guessing about it. Python helped you... pay it forward!

Comment: You are using a single name for many things: `class MediaFile:` - your class, `from MediaFile import MediaFile` - some other module and a class contained in that module,  `MediaFile[i] = MediaFile(name, filepath, extention)` a variable containing a list. These should all have different names so that you don't overwrite one with another.

Comment: @tdelaney Probably, `class MediaFile` is in a file named `MediaFile.py` and the `import ` in a sibling file.

Comment: @gold_cy I think there are two different source files for the OP's code. The second one starts at the `import` lines.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - yes, its likely true. OP could easily post a working example but instead posts something with incorrect indenting and merged files which make no sense. The whole question is confusing... parallel lists of the parts plus the parts in a class object... ??? I commented on the code he posted on purpose hoping a better version is forthcoming.

Comment: @tdelaney I can see the confusion there. I don't see where the lists are used, so I ignored them.

Comment: Please update your code to indicate if there are separate files and what the file names are.

Comment: Please share the **entire** error message, as well as a [mcve]. The code you posted looks broken, it’s difficult to tell what’s going on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should use a list of `MediaFile` objects. First you need to create the list:

```
media_files = []
```

Then you append elements to the list in your for loop:

```
media_files.append(MediaFile(name, filepath, extention))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list and then store your objects there:

Below is the code:

```
#Define class in file named MediaFile.py
class MediaFile:

def __init__(self, file_name, file_path, file_type, file_comment=None, categorys=None, playlists=None):
        self.file_name = file_name
        self.file_path = file_path
        self.file_type = file_type
        self.file_comment = file_comment
        self.categorys = categorys
        self.playlists = playlists
```

```
    # New file which contains actual code:
    from MediaFile import MediaFile
    import os.path

    filenames = []
    filepaths = []
    fileextentions = []
    # empty list to store objects
    media_list=[]

    d = input('Enter a path to organise: ')
    for path in os.listdir(d):
        full_path = os.path.join(d, path)
        i=0
        if os.path.isfile(full_path):
            filepath = full_path
            name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(full_path))[0]
            extention = os.path.splitext(full_path)[1]
            i+=1
            # append the objects to a list
            media_list.append(MediaFile(name, filepath, extention))
```

Comment: this answer doesn't make much sense because how can you import the class within itself when you are defining it?